# TChrome Tabs Paint Error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, tchromium

I want do a Tabs for my TChromium.
When i opening 2 or more Tabs, they look bad, like this:

[image]

Please, help me to fix this problem :(
Also, please, look at this theme - [TChromium ChromeTabs Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682829/tchromium-chrometabs-not-working)
**Thanks**

P.s. If it means something, i have this in my USES:

```
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, cefvcl, jpeg, ShellApi, ceflib, Vcl.Buttons,
  Vcl.Menus, Vcl.ComCtrls, clipbrd, System.Actions, Vcl.ActnList, Registry,
  Vcl.ImgList, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, ChromeTabs,

  {$IFDEF DELPHI2010_UP}
  ChromeTabsGlassForm,
  {$ENDIF}

  ChromeTabsTypes,
  ChromeTabsUtils,
  ChromeTabsControls,
  ChromeTabsClasses;
```

Comment: None of the code you posted seems to be related for the problem you can see. Have you tried to drop a `TChromeTabs` component on a form from a plain new project ? Do you have double buffer of a form enabled ? I've never noticed something like this when using that component.

Comment: Yes i've tried to create a new project and place TChromeTabs there, but nothing changes. Yes, i have Double Buffer of my Form Enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `DoubleBuffered` property of your form to False or drop the `TChromeTabs` component e.g. on a `TPanel` which will have double buffer disabled.

Comment: Thanks :) Please, help me too with this problems - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682829/tchromium-chrometabs-not-working   I'm newby in Delphi, and i have many troubles :(

Comment: Ah, nice to see a solution that sets `DoubleBuffered` to `False`. A victory for the good guys!

Comment: DoubleBuffered its bad ?